# IOException - Leiningen REPL crashing while typing

Tags: java, io, clojure

I'm coding in Clojure and have been using Lein's REPL thoroughly. But recently it's been crashing while I'm typing, especially while opening or closing maps or parenthesis, with the following error message:

```
    IOException Recurso temporariamente indisponível
    java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes (FileInputStream.java:-2)
    java.io.FileInputStream.read (FileInputStream.java:255)
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill (BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    java.io.BufferedInputStream.read (BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.run (NonBlockingInputStream.java:294)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Bye for now!
```

"Recurso temporariamente indisponível" means "Resource temporarily unavailable" in English. This message is dumped right at stdout, no line feed is printed. Also, notice that the stack trace points to the line "-2" at FileInputStream.java, which is really weird. I haven't found a single comment about an error like this online.

I'm using Leiningen v2.7.1 from SDKMAN package manager. I was using 2.8.1 and 2.9.0 before, but changing didn't change anything. I'm using Java  8.0.202-amzn from SDKMAN too.

Comment: I'm having the same problema with Leiningen 2.8.1 on Java 1.8.0_201 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: Same here. You can work around this by simply running the command "clojure" to get a REPL. It's a bit disturbing, though. Bottom line is Leiningen is crashing while attempting to read keyboard input.

Comment: We released Leiningen 2.9.0 on sdkman just yesterday, could you maybe try if that fixes it?

We also have 2.9.1 in the pipeline because of https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2530

Comment: @wink nice! I'll try that and let you know :)

Comment: Well, it seems fine now. But I'll keep using it for a day or two before calling it off! Thanks!

Comment: @wink I upgraded and it did seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried to upgrade to leinegen 2.9.0 and now I got this `NoSuchElementException`: https://pastebin.com/n5hCPX19